# How to restrict GoogleAuth to specific set of users

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

The trouble I am facing is that I want to restrict the google O auth to some specific users only or users whose email address ends with @xyz.ac.in.

It can achieved using the javascript but how one can do it from google cloud console.

Also note that I'm currently in testing phase in api.

Comment: Do not mix authentication and authorization. Google Auth, authenticate user: Is the user a real user, with correct credentials? If you must authorize only some users, you need to filter the user after the authentication. Some Google Cloud Service, like Cloud IAM can do that. Detail more your use case to narrow the used service and the possible solution

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, I want that only those users with having "@xyz.ac.in" must be able to authenticate rest must not be allowed. Like similar to google forms where we restrict google form for a specific organization employee's email.

Comment: Google OAuth and Google Cloud are separate services. I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish. Edit your post to be clear on the problem you are trying to solve. Note: Anyone with a Google account can authenticate. Google Cloud must have an IAM policy that allows that authenticated user to be authorized. In Google Cloud IAM you define which users have access.

Comment: @AkhilAgrawal, what service are you using?

Comment: As stated before, you need to manage your own list of white listed users, all users will be able to signin (that is what the product does), your platform should determine which users are allowed within your infrastructure.